# ctx.content in command and event difference (discord.py)

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

In discord.py is there some option how i can get access to msg.content (or ctx.content how everyone uses it) under a command ? Below you can see 2 examples of what i mean. The first one is event and i simply copy the message and let the bot to send it back. The second is command but there the msg.content doesnt work. My problem is that i dont want to use events so much and have everything under a command.

```
@bot.event  
async def on_message(msg):
    chat = bot.get_channel(797224597443051611)
    if msg.channel.id != channel:
        return
    if msg.content.startswith("!rps"):
        message = str(msg.content)
        await chat.send(message)
```

Someone types !rps hello. Outpup in discord is !rps hello

```
@bot.command()
async def rps(msg):
    if msg.channel.id != channel:
        return
    message = str(msg.content)
    await msg.send(message)
```

Someone types !rps hello (my prefix is !). Output is error in console:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'content'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the rest of the message of a command, you need to pass another argument. This argument will include all the messages that's sent after `!rps`. Also, using `ctx` instead of `msg` is better in commands.

```py
@bot.command()
async def rps(ctx, *, args):
    if ctx.channel.id != channel:
        return
    await ctx.send(args)
```

In this code, `args` argument includes all the messages after the `!rps`.

Answer (score 3):

Commands always take `commands.Context` as the first argument, also you should call it `ctx` instead of `msg`, to access the message content you can use `ctx.message.content`

```py
@bot.command()
async def rps(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.id != channel:
        return

    message = str(ctx.message.content)
    await ctx.send(message)
```

Take a look at the [commands introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands)